# Scroll view not scrolled when setting the height of the child view to Ti.UI.SIZE Titanium

Tags: titanium, scrollview, titanium-mobile

I have a scroll view which has a content height to `auto`
and inside of it i have a view which contain all the UI element i'm using
but my problem is when i set the height of the view to `Ti.UI.SIZE`

the scroll view not scrolled it's just scrolled in case of i add a fixed number e.g. 2000 to the child view height

Here is the code

```
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    contentWidth : 'auto',
    contentHeight : 'auto',
    backgroundColor : '#fff',
    showVerticalScrollIndicator : false,
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator : false,
    height : "100%",
    width : "100%",
    top : 36.6
});

var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : '#fff',
    borderRadius : 0,
    height :Ti.UI.SIZE,
    width : Ti.UI.FILL
});
```

i don't any extra space at the bottom of the view so how i can accomplish this ,and thanks in advance

Comment: Do you add anything else in your **view**?

Comment: yes i added labels ,slider amd textfeild

Comment: Can you paste the whole code, cause scrollview will only scroll when the data( i.e views, label, etc ) overflows the screen.

Comment: I had a similar problem and I ended up with avoiding 'Ti.UI.SIZE' and manipulated the height of the child view in my js code whenever a child view was added. Maybe you will find another solution since the one I used results in really messy code but at least it worked for me!

Comment: thanks @RobinEllerkmann it worked for me now but i got another problem is that the layout became too slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have fixed my problem with this

```
 var padding_view = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : "transparent",
    top : "36.6dp",
    left : "11dp",
    right : "11dp",
    bottom:"0dp",
});
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    contentWidth : '100%',
    contentHeight : 'auto',
    backgroundColor : '#fff',
    showVerticalScrollIndicator : false,
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator : false,
    top : "36.6dp",
    bottom:"22dp",
});

var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : '#fff',
    height :Ti.UI.SIZE, 
    width : Ti.UI.SIZE
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try It:

```
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    contentWidth : 'auto',
    contentHeight : 'auto',
    backgroundColor : '#fff',
    showVerticalScrollIndicator : false,
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator : false,
    height: Titanium.UI.FILL,
    width : "100%",
    top : 36.6
});

var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : '#fff',
    borderRadius : 0,
    height :Ti.UI.SIZE,
    width : Ti.UI.FILL
});
```

Comment: can u send xml file also

Comment: just comment contentwidth and height then check it

Comment: for debugging try to give bordercolor and check that scrollView and view height so you will understand where it is placed

Comment: both view and scroll view border go outside the window from the bottom